# Shorten code vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to shorten these codes? If yes, how? Thanks for your answer guys.

```
    Private Sub txtFirstName_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtFirstName.GotFocus
        lblFirstName.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtLastName_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtLastName.GotFocus
        lblLastName.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtMiddleName_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtMiddleName.GotFocus
        lblMiddleName.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtAddress_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtAddress.GotFocus
        lblAddress.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtContact_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtContact.GotFocus
        lblContact.Visible = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make it shorter, sorry.

Comment: @Aominè : I guess I just proved otherwise. ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its asking for a review, best over at [**code review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If my answer **didn't** solve your problem or doesn't work please explain what's wrong/what isn't working and I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Since your labels and text boxes essentially have the same name (it's only the prefix that's different) you can:

1. Bind all `GetFocus` events to a single event handler.
2. Get the `sender`'s name (`sender` is the control that raised the event), remove the `txt` prefix and replace it with `lbl`.
3. Look for a control by the new name (`lbl...`).
4. If found, make it visible.

In code it'd look like this:

```
Private Sub TextBoxes_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtFirstName.GotFocus, txtLastName.GotFocus, txtMiddleName.GotFocus, txtAddress.GotFocus, txtContact.GotFocus
    Const NamePrefix As String = "txt"
    Const NewPrefix As String = "lbl"

    Dim ctrl As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)
    If ctrl IsNot Nothing AndAlso ctrl.Name.StartsWith(NamePrefix) Then 'Check if the sender's name starts with our prefix.
        Dim NewName As String = NewPrefix & ctrl.Name.Remove(0, NamePrefix.Length) 'Remove the old prefix and replace it with the new one.
        Dim Controls As Control() = Me.Controls.Find(NewName, True) 'Look for the control of our new name.

        If Controls.Length > 0 Then 'Did we find one?
            Controls(0).Visible = True 'Make it visible.
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: First +1 ;). Although you can handle all the events in a single event handler and reduce the code duplication a bit. for readability and maintainability purposes, it's better for OP to proceed with their current approach.

Comment: @Aominè : How's that? I can understand readability (apart from that _lots_ of repetitive code is also harder to read), but unless he wants to exclude some controls this, I'd say, is much easier to maintain. When having lots of event handlers you can sometimes get confused looking through them all, missing for instance that one of them isn't attached any longer because you have removed and re-added a control.

Comment: @Aominè : Though I do agree that his code is easier to maintain _**if**_ he needs to exclude some controls or do some other, per-control specific operation on some of them. :)

Comment: it's easier to maintain because you know exactly which event handler is handling what event therefore if you were to add some additional logic for a specific case say `Contact` then you don't need extra `if then` conditions to make sure it only applies to a specific control.

Comment: I was just writing that.. haha ;)

Comment: The fact that you need code specific to a particular control is not a reason not to use the pattern demonstrated here.  You can simply add another handler for that event and put the specific code there while leaving the common code in the common event handler. Also, to say that separate event handlers is easier to maintain is, in my opinion, simply false. Any change to common functionality requires multiple code changes and if there is no control-specific code then what's the point? If you ever encounter that situation then make the change then.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : True. I forgot that one can simply add another handler. :)

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx): *The GotFocus and LostFocus events are low-level focus events that are tied to the WM_KILLFOCUS and WM_SETFOCUS Windows messages. Typically, the GotFocus and LostFocus events are only used when updating UICues or when writing custom controls. Instead the Enter and Leave events should be used for all controls...*

Comment: I dont understand why any of this, one handler is ok for this case. Sender is the control, why not cast it as a control and set the visibility property? Then there is no need for all that bloat code... Also checking the name isnt needed because it only handles the controls assigned to it.

Comment: @Codexer : Because he's changing the visibility of a _**different**_ control than `sender`. If `sender` is `txtFirstName` he wants `lblFirstName` to become visible. Notice the `lbl` prefix rather than `txt`.

Comment: My bad, an oversee on my part.

Comment: @Codexer : It happens to all of us every now and then. No harm done. ;)

Comment: Make a UserControl with a Label and TextBox.  Now it's very simple.

Comment: @LarsTech : An even better suggestion. I mainly focused on the OP's original implementation, in case he didn't want to/couldn't change the layout.